# If $x^9-x^5+x-2=0$ , how to prove $\sqrt[11]{3}<x<\sqrt[10]{3}$ ，$\sqrt[7]{2}<x<\sqrt[6]{2}$.

Tags: inequality

If $x^9-x^5+x-2=0$ is known, 
how to prove   $\sqrt[11]{3}<x<\sqrt[10]{3}$ ，$\sqrt[7]{2}<x<\sqrt[6]{2}$。

Comment: That's "either-or", I assume.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $x^9-x^5+x=2 \implies \dfrac{((x^4)^3+1)}{x^4+1}=\dfrac{2}{x}$

**Spoiler**:

Wolframalpha gives only real solution to this, i.e $x \approx 1.112$, which is in between $3^{\frac{1}{11}}$ and $3^{\frac{1}{10}}$ **OR**(as Thomas Andrews says) $2^{\frac{1}{6}}$ and $3^{\frac{1}{7}}$  .

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** $9x^8-5x^4+1>0$.

**Hint 2** An increasing continuous function $f(x)$ has a root in an interval $(a,b)$ if and only if $f(a)<0<f(b)$.